# How to get two vagrant boxes to talk to each other?

Tags: vagrant

Let's say I make two vagrant boxes, `foo` and `bar`:

```
$ mkdir -p foo bar
$ pushd foo; vagrant init hashicorp/precise32; vagrant up; popd
$ pushd bar; vagrant init hashicorp/precise32; vagrant up; popd
```

Now let's say I start an HTTP server on `foo`:

```
$ cd foo
$ vagrant ssh -c 'python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080
```

My question is, how can I get `bar` to communicate (e.g. via `curl`) with `foo`?

```
$ cd bar
$ vagrant ssh -c 'curl http://????'
```

Answer (score 2):

Although the question does not make it clear, I think this older question is asking:`if the *same* development machine is running two vagrant instances, how can an app running on`foo`fetch data from a url on`bar`.

If so, I ran into this recently for my two Rails apps(each running in a separate vagrant instance on the same development machine).

The two-part 'trick' if `foo` wants to fetch data from `bar`, is:

1) each Vagrant files needs a line:

```
config.vm.network :private_network, ip: PVT_NETWORK
```

where PVT_NETWORK is a local IP, is different for each Vagrant file, and probably needs to be in the same subnet. For example PVT_NETWORK might be 192.168.50.50 (foo) and 192.168.50.51 (bar)

2) `foo` accesses `bar` via the PVT_NETWORK IP address **not** the "real" IP you would use with a web browser.

In my Rails example, I also have each app running on a different port, so `foo` is on localhost:3000 and `bar` is on localhost:3001, so `foo` would access a url on `bar` via

```
http://192.168.50.51:3001/some_url
```

Answer (score 0):

If the two servers are in the same network and no ACL between them (local boxes) they can communicate with each other after configuring the network.

configure the vagrant file:

```
# Disable automatic box update checking. If you disable this, then
# boxes will only be checked for updates when the user runs
# `vagrant box outdated`. This is not recommended.
# config.vm.box_check_update = false

# Create a forwarded port mapping which allows access to a specific port
# within the machine from a port on the host machine. In the example below,
# accessing "localhost:8080" will access port 80 on the guest machine.
# config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080

# Create a private network, which allows host-only access to the machine
# using a specific IP.
# config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"

# Create a public network, which generally matched to bridged network.
# Bridged networks make the machine appear as another physical device on
# your network.
# config.vm.network "public_network"
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on your answer? It looks like you just copied the config that was already in the vagrant file. What changes/configurations are you suggesting they make?