# How to connect two vagrant boxes

Tags: curl, connection, vagrant, virtual-machine, homestead

I have laravel and homestead running on one virtual machine. I am using the default ip configuration, so my site is running at 192.168.10.10. Now I needed to install another vm and used the scotchbox to use apache. This box runs at 192.168.33.10. Everything is working just fine, but now I need to connect those two. I want to use a curl request from my scotchbox to access an api on homestead. I tried using the hostname from my host file, which isn't working. And trying to curl to 192.168.10.10 from within the scotchbox is giving me a 403.

[This didn't help me.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30492761/how-to-get-two-vagrant-boxes-to-talk-to-each-other)

Any suggestions on how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I generally do this using [multi-machine setup](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/multi-machine/)

> In order to facilitate communication within machines in a
>   multi-machine setup, the various networking options should be used. In
>   particular, the private network can be used to make a private network
>   between multiple machines and the host.

Thats what I am currently using - In my Vagrantfile I have multiple VMs, all setup with `private_network` and static IP. I have no issues to ping one host from the other.